# ng-repeat does not work well

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs, and trying this, but not sure why is it not working. I used quite a number of solutions found here, but none works.

Here is my array that is assigned to $scope.data_params

[image]

Here is my code in HTML:-

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data_params">
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
```

Code in JS:-

```
    $scope.data_params.push(result_params.dealers); 
   console.log($scope.data_params);
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: @AkashKC The HTML part no output were displayed.

Comment: Can you please test with making change with `$scope.data_params.push(result_params.dealers[0]);`

Comment: @AkashKC Done here, here is the result,
http://imgur.com/a/r2eHB

Comment: you are not getting any data in html?

Comment: @AkashKC Nope... I just don't understand why.

Comment: Your issue is with result_params.dealers. So, you are inserting nested array in data_params. You need to fix that part

Comment: @AkashKC Fixed as Marcelo suggested, but still problem still exist

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: @AkashKC No data were being displayed, there is no error or anything. Just empty table.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to access to the 0 element,
Try:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data_params[0]">
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it your `data_params` is a 1 length array that houses a 10 length array with the objects you want. You need to repeat over the 10 length array, not the 1 length.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data_params[0]">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can change this line `$scope.data_params.push(result_params.dealers)` to `$scope.data_params = result_params.dealers` and avoid this nesting of arrays.

Comment: @MuthaFury Can you please post a code example that replicates the issue then?

Comment: the weird thing is, I have declare a few scope, others seems to work fine, only this scope it doesn't show the result in HTML part

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data is an array that contains an array of your items. Try ng-repeating on the inner-array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data_params[0]">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track by $index:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data_params track by $index">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
```